# Is it possible to track all settings/configs/patches etc across the OS that may affect an eclipse Project?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, maven

This may be an absurd question (plus I am unsure how to best Tag it) but lets me explain 1st. For the last few months I have regularly had stupid issues with my eclipse project when I have made no changes to anything related to the project (That I am aware of). For example, When I finished yesterday Everything worked perfectly, I came in today and suddenly on first run I had a the error `javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder$ConfigurationError: Provider com.sun.xml.stream.ZephyrParserFactory not found` so I had to add a new dependency to my pom, one I had never needed prior to this error, but this in turned cause another error `java.lang.LinkageError` (if someone has in sight to what is wrong with this specific error, while its not the main question I would love to know). Now I am confident this is completely an environment issue as my team mates are running the same project on there machine with no issue and I even tried redeploying the project currently hosted on the DEV environment (which is in working order) to my local machine

So What I'm asking is is there a way I can create a kind of log of everything that is used (or referenced) by this project each time it is run successfully, and when I say everything I refer to things like changes to Maven config, weblogic/tomcat, java patches, eclipse plugins, OS patches (windows 7 in mycase), build paths, project configs.... basically anything eclipse would use to build and deploy the project

I realize the list is most likely massive, but if it was possible to do this on each run (or as an extra flag or something) then it wouldn't be too difficult to compare the log of a successful run with that of a non successful run (this could later be automated)

As I said This may be absurd but if possible it would be a very useful tool.

Comment: Do you use a version control tool? SVN, Git, Mercurial, Bazaar or whatever ?

Comment: @khmarbaise yes, we use PVCS

Comment: Use PVCS to see what has changed in pom files which is related to maven and in your project. May be misunderstand your question.

Comment: @khmarbaise its not them Pom, and its not any of the files contained in the actual project itself because they are all the same ( I even recreate the project in a new workspace with the current PVCS files)

Answer (score 0):

Are you in sole control of your eclipse installation/updates?

Could it be that eclipse installation updates (if provided via site IT) are causing you issues?

Comment: I control over the eclipse installation and updates but IT can patch things without notice